# Any side effects to having a large number of mutexes?

Tags: go, mutex

In my go code, I've a no. of structs that need mutexes:

```
type vitalMacs struct {
        mu   *sync.RWMutex
        macs map[string]bool
}

//macInfo would store oui info
type macInfo struct {
        mu       *sync.RWMutex
        infoDict map[string]*string
}

var (
        NetOPMutex  sync.RWMutex
        ipMacGlobal = make(map[string]string)
        macInfoVar  = macInfo{mu: &NetOPMutex}
        vitalMacsVar = vitalMacs{mu: &NetOPMutex}
        //vitalMacsVar = vitalMacs{mu: &sync.RWMutex{}} // <- like this 
)
```

I could use `NetOPMutex` for all of them, or, have new mutexes set as `&sync.RWMutex{}` - which made me wonder:
Are there any side effects to having a large number different of mutexes in your code?

Not trying to avoid mutexes, you gotta guard what you gotta guard, no question there.

I know that if I use the single mutex, things would have to wait for each other and play nice. On the other hand, would having a large number of different mutexes (30+) manifest as higher cpu util or as more time in user vs kernel mode etc?

Comment: One downside for mutexes is that they are bigger than you expect. In order to avoid problems locking cache lines a mutex is always padded out to 64 bytes each. I know that some programs use a hash of addresses to mutexes in order to have a lock per tree node but only use 4,096 mutexes. That was a C program and I don't know if the same idea would work in Go.

Comment: [bigcache](https://github.com/allegro/bigcache) uses sharding for its in memory cache. Rather than use a single very contentious lock (e.g. a vanillia `map`), the memory map is split into (by default) 1024 shards. So when doing updates, one shard may be locked, while the other 1023 shards will have uncontentious access. Key lookups use hashing - and this is where the shard-count must be a power of 2 comes in - applying a mask to the has hash determines which shard a key's data belongs. So with an even distribution spread of keys to shards - the number of contentious locks is minimized.

Answer (score 3):

[`sync.Mutex`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Mutex) and [`sync.RWMutex`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#RWMutex) are struct types, having mutexes is the same thing as having ordinary struct values. Are there any side effects of having many struct values in your app? Obviously not.

Creating a mutex does not involve magic. It's equivalent to just creating a struct value.

Using mutexes also does not involve magic. Check the sources: [`Mutex.Lock()`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Mutex.Lock) and [`Mutex.Unlock()`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Mutex.Unlock). They do not launch goroutines or do something that consumes CPU.

Do not use a single mutex just to save / spare some memory. Use multiple mutexes if appropriate to reduce / mitigate contention for the locks.